# C++ Core Guidelines: Lifetime - why does the following code trigger a warning?

Tags: c++, static-analysis, cpp-core-guidelines

When compiling the following code in Visual Studio 2019 while using the "C++ Core Check Lifetime Rules", I get "warning C26486: Don't pass a pointer that may be invalid to a function. Parameter 0 '@vA' in call to 'std::vector<'LifeTimeWarning'::'2'::XY,std::allocator<'LifeTimeWarning'::'2'::XY> >::push_back' may be invalid (lifetime.3).":

```
struct XY { int c1; };
vector<XY> vA, vB;
vA.push_back({1});
vB.push_back(vA.at(0));
```

The warning disappears, if I replace the struct-type with a simple integer, or if I assign `vA.at(0)` to a temporary variable, and then push back the variable to `vB`. Why is that? Also, how is this code "unsafe" in the first place?

Comment: Not able to reproduce the warning - live - https://godbolt.org/z/MPboYfPTM

Comment: It seems that Lifetime analysis is not supported on this website, because this example does not trigger a warning either, whereas in Visual studio this example shows two warnings: https://godbolt.org/z/88x86f9dT

Comment: Seems like a false positive. Now if you were doing `vA.push_back(vA.at(0));`, that might be more interesting.

Comment: Yes, it seems like it is a false positive... because, if I select "Clang -Wlifetime" on Godbolt, it does not create a warning, but certain other cases with obvious lifetime violations (like the one I linked) do.

Comment: You should report this to Microsoft. In VS: Menu Help/"Send Feedback"/"Report a Problem...".